# AutoHotkey to map Right Winkey and TAB to LWin and t

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I changed keyboards. Now I have a right windows key but not left. Left work(ed)s for my simple script of

```
#TAB
    send #t
return
```

this cycles through the windows on my taskbar.

but it doesn't work when using the right windows key.

Left win and tab act normal, right win and tab don't get recognized.

Left win and 't' act normal, right win and 't' pops up the hover preview for my first window, but doesn't autorepeat/cycle through them like if you use the left win key with 't'-- so, SOMETHING different seems to be going on.

I love AHK but random bits like this always stump me :( :( :(

edit: here's the readout from Key History/Script Info. I don't have ANY other lines in this script or my other one watching for Win keys--

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Window
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
74  03F     u   0.06    F5              
74  03F     d   0.11    F5              
74  03F     u   0.06    F5              
74  03F     d   0.09    F5              
74  03F     u   0.06    F5              
74  03F     d   0.09    F5              
74  03F     u   0.08    F5              
5C  15C     d   1.25    RWin            // I tested Rwin by itself
5C  15C     u   0.13    RWin            
5C  15C     d   0.89    RWin            Start menu
5C  15C     u   0.06    RWin            // next line I used RWin and hit tab
5C  15C     d   4.98    RWin            D:\My Documents\Box Sync\AutoHotkey.ahk - AutoHotkey v1.1.05.06
09  00F h   d   0.22    Tab             
5B  15B i   d   0.00    LWin            
A2  01D i   d   0.02    LControl        
A2  01D i   u   0.00    LControl        
5C  15C i   u   0.00    RWin            
54  014 i   d   0.00    T               
54  014 i   u   0.00    T               
5B  15B i   u   0.01    LWin            
A2  01D i   d   0.02    LControl        
5C  15C i   d   0.00    RWin            
A2  01D i   u   0.00    LControl        
09  00F s   u   0.11    Tab             
09  00F h   d   0.84    Tab             
5B  15B i   d   0.00    LWin            
A2  01D i   d   0.01    LControl        
A2  01D i   u   0.00    LControl        
5C  15C i   u   0.00    RWin            
54  014 i   d   0.00    T               
54  014 i   u   0.00    T               
5B  15B i   u   0.02    LWin            
A2  01D i   d   0.01    LControl        
5C  15C i   d   0.00    RWin            
A2  01D i   u   0.00    LControl        
09  00F s   u   0.11    Tab             
5C  15C     u   0.90    RWin            
A2  01D i   d   0.00    LControl        
A2  01D i   u   0.00    LControl        
74  03F     d   0.70    F5
```

and here's what it looks like with the left Win key.

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Window
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
74  03F     d   0.13    F5              
74  03F     u   0.05    F5              
74  03F     d   0.16    F5              
74  03F     u   0.08    F5              
74  03F     d   0.33    F5              
74  03F     u   0.09    F5              
74  03F     d   0.64    F5              
74  03F     u   0.11    F5              
5B  15B     d   5.77    LWin            
09  00F h   d   0.16    Tab             
5B  15B i   d   0.00    LWin            
54  014 i   d   0.02    T               
54  014 i   u   0.00    T               
09  00F s   u   0.13    Tab             
5B  15B i   u   0.01    LWin            
A2  01D i   d   0.02    LControl        
5B  15B i   d   0.00    LWin            
A2  01D i   u   0.00    LControl        
09  00F h   d   0.97    Tab             
5B  15B i   d   0.00    LWin            
54  014 i   d   0.02    T               
54  014 i   u   0.00    T               
5B  15B i   u   0.01    LWin            
A2  01D i   d   0.02    LControl        
5B  15B i   d   0.00    LWin            
A2  01D i   u   0.00    LControl        
09  00F s   u   0.11    Tab             
09  00F h   d   1.06    Tab             
5B  15B i   d   0.00    LWin            
54  014 i   d   0.02    T               
54  014 i   u   0.00    T               
5B  15B i   u   0.01    LWin            
A2  01D i   d   0.02    LControl        
5B  15B i   d   0.00    LWin            
A2  01D i   u   0.00    LControl        
09  00F s   u   0.08    Tab             
5B  15B     u   1.18    LWin            
A2  01D i   d   0.00    LControl        
A2  01D i   u   0.00    LControl        
74  03F     d   5.02    F5              D:\My Documents\Box Sync\AutoHotkey.ahk - AutoHotkey v1.1.05.06
```

I guess my next question to google is, "what's LControl doing in there?"

Answer (score -1):

This code works with both <kbd>Win</kbd> keys:

```
#TAB::
    send, {Win Down}t{Win Up}
return
```

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*

Comment: Why downvote? My code works and does what Rancur3p1c asks for.

Comment: This doesn't work either, but I'd like to know why-- it does what the others do, which is just insert "tttttt", one t with each tab press. I presume whoever downvoted knows...

Comment: @Rancur3p1c My code sends `Win`+`t` when you press `Win`+`TAB`. You can press any `Win` button. Does that works for you? Also which version of AutoHotkey are you using? Always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!

Comment: yes, it doesn't work...yes, latest version

Comment: @Rancur3p1c 1) Run it with administrator privileges. 2) If it does not helps treat the buttons that are not working as specil keys, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24927828/1601703

Comment: everything I run is administrator privileges O:D. will look into using special keys for it instead thx